# Excel2019: Execute conditional formatting over a certain number of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

First of all, please excuse the confusing description of the requirements, but I struggle to formulate this question in a concrete and concise way. So I'll try an example and a corresponding explanation.

I would like to use conditional formatting in Excel 2019 to select a certain range that is not the same as the range to be checked. In other words, in my example, I am checking between `B3:K3` and would like to include the cell found (highlighted in `orange`) and the two neighboring cells (highlighted in `yellow`) in the conditional formatting if there is a match.

**How is it possible to define this in one rule?**

[image: excel.png]

Answer (score 0):

You should define 2 rules:
`=$B3="m"` for the range `$B$3:$D$5` and
`=$G3="m"` for the range `$G$3:$I$5`
`$` sign before `B` and `G` is necessary.